# MYSQL Limit 1 row of multiple rows with same value in a column

Tags: mysql

my table is like this

```
id - user_id - car - color
1  -    3    - BMW - red
2  -    5    - JAG - blue
3  -    3    - JEEP- pink
4  -    5    - MERC- blue
5  -    6    - BMW - black
```

And I want to return one car per user, not two, doesn't matter which is chosen. What would my query look like?
Thank you so much for your help!
Dex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM user_cars GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: I think he will need a join statement like `select user.*, cars.car, cars.color from user left join cars on cars.user_id = user.id group by user_id`

Comment: @user973254: don't assume that posters have normalized structures. You'll find the rule is that most DON'T.

Comment: Looking at the schema again it might be normalized since I don't see any user data other than the id.

Comment: @DexCurl Be *very* careful when using this kind of "loose" GROUP BY with MySQL. See [GROUP BY and HAVING with Hidden Columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html). For this reason, I believe [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814030/mysql-limit-1-row-of-multiple-rows-with-same-value-in-a-column/7814078#7814078) is preferable.

Answer (score 2):

you need to group everything

```
group by user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.user_id, t.car, t.color
    FROM (SELECT user_id, MIN(id) AS MinId
              FROM YourTable
              GROUP BY user_id) q
        INNER JOIN YourTable t
            ON q.MinId = t.id
```